# Choosing DB context when adding identity to existing project

Tags: c#

I'm trying to add Identity to an existing and working MVC project.

When used this command `Add-Migration CreateIdentitySchema` I got error message: `'More than one DbContext was found. Specify which one to use. Use the '-Context' parameter for PowerShell commands and the '--context' parameter for dotnet commands.'` and I chose the existing DB context that I have previously created for the main functionality of the application and now it shows `'There is already an object named 'ExpenseReport' in the database.'` so it's trying to recreate my initial model.

Should I have a separate DB Context for Identity and if yes how to connect user to data from the other context?

Answer (score 0):

So, i think you can use several DbContexts with different connections (just need to write it in your Startup class) or you need to use pattern "DbContext Factory". You can read more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43120132/giving-database-context-to-object-factory)  .

Hope it will help you.